# Fast computation of $x^{1/p}$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $p=2^{n}$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with bit shifts?

Tags: floating-point, bit-strings

There is plenty of literature regarding the legendary [Fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) routine from Quake, but can we do something similar to compute $x^{1/p}$ as given in the title?

Given that $p$ is a power of 2, there should be some clever trick using bit shifts to achieve this.

Comment: If $p$ is a power of $2$ you can just apply the square root algorithm multiple times in a row.

Comment: @quarague: it should be simpler than that. There's a step in FastInvSqrt where you divide by $2$ and you should be able to replace that with dividing by $2^n$. Possibly the "magic constants" should be modified, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Is known, that $y^{\large 2^{\Large p}}$ can be calculated by $p$ multiplication operations. Besides, is not a problem to calculate the MSB position of the result $y=x^{\large\frac1{\large 2^p}}.$

This allows to get the result y, bit after bit, over $pM$ multiplications, where $M$ is a quantity of bits of the result.